# JavaScript: Like-Counter with Memory

Tags: javascript, cookies, filereader, web-storage

Complete - Edited Once

I am looking to create a *Like Counter* with persistent **Memory**!

Right now, my project is stored on a USB-Drive and I'm not thinking of uploading my semi-finished site to the Internet just yet. I'm carrying it around, plugging and working.
A feature of the site, is a *Heart Counter* and *Like Counter*, respective with their symbolic icons.
I have a little sideline JavaScript file that has a dozen functions to handle the click-events and such - such as the Number Count of the counters.

But, as the values of the counters are *auto-assigned* to *Temporary Memory* - if you were to reload the page - the counter number would reset to it's default, Zero. A huge headache...

## Reading from .txt

I thought of using the experimental `ReadFile()` object to handle the problem - but I soon found that it needed a user-put file to operate (from my examinations).
Here's my attempt:

```
if (heartCount || likeCount >= 1) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var readerResults = reader.readAsText(heartsAndLikes.txt);
    //return readerResults
    alert(readerResults);
}
```

When loaded, the page runs through standard operations, except for the above.
This, in my opinion, would have been the ideal solution...

## Reading from Cookies

Cookies now don't seem like an option as it resides on a per-computer basis.
They are stored on the computer's SSD, not in the JavaScript File... sad...

## HTML5 Web Storage

Using the new Web Storage will be of big help, probably. But again, it is on a per-computer basis, no matter how beautiful the system is...

```
localStorage.heartCount = 0 //Originally...
function heartButtonClicked() {
    if (localStorage.heartCount) {
        localStorage.heartCount = Number(localStorage.heartCount) + 1
    }
    document.getElementById('heartCountDisplay').innerHTML = localStorage.heartCount
} //Function is tied to the heartCountButton directly via the 'onclick' method
```

However, I am questioning whether web storage can be carried over on a USB-Drive...

## Summarised ideas

Currently, I am looking to Reading and Editing the files, as it's most ideal to my situation. But...
Which would you use? Would you introduce a new method of things?
Please, tell me about it! :)

Comment: This is a small web app with some counter values that you want to persist? And do you want the values to be shared amongst users?

Comment: Too many words. Why do you want to store it in a file? Or more accurately, why do *you* want to store it in a file rather than use the browser's persistence mechanism?

Comment: Please [edit] your question down to the least about of text necessary to get across your question. It seems like you're asking a very broad, possibly opinion-based question regarding "what's a good way of saving data".

Comment: @BenAston Not really a web-app, but a website on a USB-thumbdrive...

Comment: @DaveNewton I'd need to have a file or it won't persist compyter-to-computer. Well, unless there happens to be a webservice that I can draw my counter values from, that auto-updates the copies.

Comment: And what's the issue with ReadFile? I mean, you seem to know all the options, and you have a specific requirement-I barely know what you're asking anymore. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DaveNewton I \*kind of\* know the parameters of ReadFile() , well- as far as I can gather from it. It needs a file destination and a 'spark' to initiate the process(es). Other than that... I too, don't know anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") { //make sure local storage is available   

if (!localStorage.heartCount) { //if heartCount is not set then set it to zero
localStorage.heartCount = 0;
}

} else {
alert('Local storage is not available');
}

function heartButtonClicked() {

if (localStorage.heartCount) { //if heartCount exists then increment it by one
    localStorage.heartCount++;
}

//display the result
document.getElementById('heartCountDisplay').innerHTML = localStorage.heartCount 
}
```

This will only work on a per computer basis and will not persist on your thumb drive. The only way I can think of to persist the data on your drive is to manually download a JSON or text file.

Comment: Seeing as you're the only person willing to answer (thanks by the way), I'll use your solution. It may or may not find a place in my project - but I'll find a way to incorporate it. Thanks again!

Comment: You are Welcome!